# Updating a Google Calendar event deletes every field I don't update using the NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, api, google-calendar-api

I am updating a google calendar event using the `Google API Nodejs client` library this way:

```
calendar.events.update(
  {
    auth: jwtClient,
    calendarId: bookingCalendarId,
    eventId: booking.googleCalendarEventId,
    resource: {
      start: { dateTime: booking.startDate };
      end: { dateTime: endDate };
    },
  }
);
```

This is updating the start and end date of an event, and this is working **but** the summary, description, location and every other field that I don't update are deleted in the calendar event.

Is it the normal behavior? I guess it is not what I should expect from an "update" function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation's example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update#examples) the event is first returned using `get`, then modified, before being resubmitted into the `update` function. This will avoid your previously set attributes to be erased.

Comment: I see, thanks! Too bad I can't just update without getting the event first.